# How to config Vagrant to serve my website on Local network?

Tags: vagrant, nat, portforwarding

I have my vagrant machine serving my sites host/guest env.

I'd like to serve (make available) also these sites across local LAN.

I believe I need to apply port_forwarding  or change config from NAT to bridged?

What do you suggest?
Sorry but I didn't find until now a comprehensive explanation, on how to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `vagrant share` to make your machine [publicly accessible over the internet](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/share/).

Just type `vagrant share` after the box is running (`vagrant up`).

You should see something like this:

```
$ vagrant share
==> default: Detecting network information for machine...
    default: Local machine address: 192.168.163.152
    default: Local HTTP port: 4567
    default: Local HTTPS port: disabled
==> default: Checking authentication and authorization...
==> default: Creating Vagrant Share session...
    default: Share will be at: ghastly-wombat-4051
==> default: Your Vagrant Share is running!
    default: Name: ghastly-wombat-4051
==> default: URL: http://ghastly-wombat-4051.vagrantshare.com
```

Note you will need an account with hashicorp / atlas account (which is free) and can be acquired [right here](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/account/new).

Comment: Nice to know, but how this would imply about security and privacy? What de-facto does vagrant share ?

Comment: @koalaok if you click the link and read about it on the site, it will do a better job of explaining it than I can in a comment!

Answer (score 0):

You can set up your Vagrant box to receive an IP from public network via a bridged interface. This way anyone in the LAN will be able to access your vagrant machine via the assigned public IP.

See vagrant docs: [Vagrant - Public network](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/public_network.html)

Comment: It seems pretty straight forward but I still didn't get anywhere. Since, I'm testing it on my laptop connected to the LAN via Wifi. Using Virtualbox as provider. When I "Vagrant up" I'm asked to choose which interface I should use for bridging. Maybe It is not working because I need to choose a different Network interface (different from wifi that is already in use by the host, i.e. use cabled ethernet instead) or the same interface can be shared by host guest(bridged)?